# can not deploy react web app to firebase project using github action

Tags: firebase, github, firebase-tools, github-actions

When I'm trying to deploy the **firebase** project using **GitHub action** that give an error

[image]

My **ci.yaml** file is:

```
name: Build and Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
      - name: Archive Production Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: dist
          path: dist
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@master
        with:
          name: dist
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting:prod
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

My Project is based on *react web app* and when I push the repo to GitHub that build using GitHub action and deploy the project to firebase.

*dist* is the public directory where production code to deploy to firebase

Comment: Since the error is occurring when using the `w9jds/firebase-action` 3rd party action it might be best to create an issue at that repository. The action author might be able to help you. https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did't use **any environment** such as for stagging and production or other aliases for this firebase project.

for more info [Deploy to multiple environments with Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/deploy-to-multiple-environments-with.html)

so only need is `deploy --only hosting`

```
- name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
          PROJECT_PATH: ./dist
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following question/answer might be the solution to your issue.

[How to add working directory to deployment in GitHub actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58352402/how-to-add-working-directory-to-deployment-in-github-actions/58352660#58352660)

You can now set the path to your firebase.json with `PROJECT_PATH`. Try changing your action settings to the following.

```
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting:prod
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
          PROJECT_PATH: ./dist
```

Answer (score 1):

change all the dist to build
it works in my case

Comment: Please explain in more detail