# How to add working directory to deployment in GitHub actions

Tags: firebase, github, github-actions

I recently moved into GitHub actions, so what I'm trying to do is host my react project in firebase when a push is done. And I used GitHub actions to this CI/CD process. And this is the main.yml that I have right now.

```
name: Build and Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Install Dependencies
        working-directory: ./my-app
        run: npm install
      - name: Build
        working-directory: ./my-app
        run: npm run build

  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master      
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

And I somehow manage to set the working directory when npm installation and project building. But in deployment I'm keep getting this error,

[image]

So what I have understood is, this error occurs due to the working directory problem. So my current project structure looks like this.

```
. (root of my GitHub repository)
└── my-app
    ├── firebase.json   <-- Git Hub action must point to this sub-dir
└── my-app-mobile
    ├── packages.json
```

So how should I do this within my firebase deployment process? If I'm wrong with the problem, What would be the problem and the answer? It seems I can't use `working-directory: ./my-app` with `uses:`

Comment: Why not use `working-directory: ./my-app` again?

Comment: it can't be used with 'uses'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I looked at the documentation for the firebase CLI and didn't see any way to set the path to your `firebase.json` via a CLI parameter. There is, however, an environment variable that stores the root directory. It's in the context of `predeploy` and `postdeploy` hooks though, so I'm not sure if the CLI will respect it.

> $PROJECT_DIR — The root directory containing firebase.json

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#environment_variables

The `w9jds/firebase-action` you are using is just a wrapper around the CLI. I'm not sure if this will work but you could try setting the project directory as follows. The reason the variable is set in a separate step is because you cannot evaluate expressions in `env` sections. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57989070/11934042) for more detail. Container actions like `w9jds/firebase-action` will have access to the variable without passing it directly via `env`.

```
      - name: Set project dir environment var
        run: echo ::set-env name=PROJECT_DIR::"$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/my-app"
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

If that doesn't work, an alternative is to fork `w9jds/firebase-action` and add a `PROJECT_PATH` parameter to the entrypoint.sh script here:
https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action/blob/master/entrypoint.sh

**Update:** [I raised a PR](https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action/pull/8) to add a `PROJECT_PATH` parameter to `w9jds/firebase-action`. You can now use the action as follows.

```
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
          PROJECT_PATH: ./my-app
```

Comment: Why not put it in the env map with FIREBASE_TOKEN?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's because you cannot evaluate expressions in `env` sections.

Comment: So the given solution is not working and I would thank you for such an explanation. Could you please tell me how to set the PROJECT_PATH with the forked repo and how to use it in the GitHub actions. At least I have to try that on also.

Comment: I've updated the solution with how to add the project path parameter in the forked version.

Comment: So this is the error now I'm getting -> "Error: Specified public directory 'build' does not exist, can't deploy hosting to site my-app"

Comment: @ShehanDhaleesha It appears that the forked version worked and you are in the correct directory now. That error is likely to be a different problem. I don't know a lot about firebase, I'm afraid, so if you can't figure it out yourself perhaps make a new question.

Comment: @ShehanDhaleesha I raised a PR to add `PROJECT_PATH` to `w9jds/firebase-action`. Please switch back to using the original author's action if you still using my fork.

Comment: Thanks for this! Works perfectly in our monorepo.

Comment: @ShehanDhaleesha were you able to solve the issue 'Error: Specified public directory 'build' does not exist, can't deploy hosting to site my-app' ?